# SQL Server Primary file group max size

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation, I am trying to run almost 100 update statement on a table say 'XX'

In SQL Server database. But it is giving me an error  tat goes something like this...

> "Could not allocate space for object
>   'dbo.XX'.'PK_*XX*_3489AE06' in
>   database 'MYDATABASE' because the
>   'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create
>   disk space by deleting unneeded files,
>   dropping objects in the filegroup,
>   adding additional files to the
>   filegroup, or setting autogrowth on
>   for existing files in the filegroup."

Please advice me what to do...
Thankx in advance

Comment: Not programming-related -> belongs on Serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

1. Check to see if your database has auto growth enabled.
2. Make sure you have available space on disk where your database file is located.

Comment: @@BOB..it has been set to unrestricted growth and moreover my drive has over 60gb of free space

Comment: @@BOB my drive has NTFS and not FAT32

Comment: Have you tried to manually grow your database?  Also, have you checked both data and log file size?  And have you run a DBCC to make sure everything is in order?  Hope one of these items helps!